# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) on terminal with commands : sudo mysql ,, and ,, mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm struggling with this problem whenever I type on terminal this command:

`sudo mysql`

or

`mysql`

or when I try to connect to a server on the mysql workbench too.

Maybe I forgot the password, please help me I checked so much solutions here on stack overflow flow but it didn't help.

Comment: According to the error, you didn't set a password for your mysql. Have you tried without password?

Comment: it is okay i fixed it ,, and yes i hade to set a password and i used  a previous answer in this website